# Creating this graph using css

Tags: html, css, graph

I need to create this image into my `HTML` using `CSS`.

[image: bar graph image]

As you can see, there is two `bar graphs aligned to the right`. each bar graph has a set of bars, numbers and texts. the text is the to left aligned right, the number is to the right aligned right, and each bar is in between the text and the number.

Like I said, I have no understanding of this level of css so please treat this as a `css newbie`

any information would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have not tried producing any code for this. I have no idea how to handle this task.

So I was able to get the text on the left but i cannot get the value on the right. Its showing up as a new line on the right

[image]

Here is my css:

```
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.horizontal .progress-bar {
  float: left;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.horizontal .progress-track {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  float:right;
  margin-left:-20px;
}

.horizontal .progress-fill {
  position: relative;
  background: #2272af;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lato","Verdana",sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.horizontal .progress-bar-label
{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding-left:215px;
}

.horizontal .progress-bar-value
{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding-right:-15px;
  /**padding:0;*/
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="progress-bar horizontal">
  <span class="progress-bar-label">test</span>
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="progress-bar-value">125</span>
  </div>
```

Not quite sure how to get the value of 125 on the right of the graph bar

Comment: Please share the code you already tested.

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel see update

Comment: Please check out this code as a start and edit your answer after that. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyBWEL

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel thanks

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel ok how do i add `text to the left of the bar`, `text to the right of the bar`, and align the entire class `progress-bar horizontal` to the right side of the container instead of starting at the left side of the container

Comment: I really suggest to take some basic css-tutorials first, sorry.

Comment: I'm actually learning as we speak. I tried setting a float left to the text just before the div that renders the bar. If you can help I'd appreciate it

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel please see updates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94532/discussion-between-sebass-van-boxel-and-jkushner).

Answer (score 0):

This is using `HTML` `CSS` and `Jquery` http://codepen.io/ntibbs/pen/MaPpKr

```
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-bar-label">test</div>
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar-value">125</div>
  </div>

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.progress-bar {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
}
.progress-bar-label {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
}
.progress-track {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 75%;
}
.progress-fill {
  position: relative;
  background: #2272af;
  height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lato","Verdana",sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.progress-bar-value {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use jquery. sorry.

Comment: I updated that code using plain javascript if that is possible for you

Comment: can you look at my updates? Id like to fix this solution

Comment: you might just need to adjust the width of div element

Comment: can you use my code and provide an example? Im having difficulty getting the pixels correct.